# Karate UI Automation - Assertion fails with message "actual value is not JSON-like" for driver.title comparison

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I am trying to use karate for UI automation but I am stuck with one basic scenario where I am trying to validate the page title

Below are my scenario steps:

```
 Scenario: Validate page title
    Given driver 'https://google.com'
    And driver.maximize()
    Then match driver.title == 'Google'
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
assertion failed: path: $.title, actual: 'Google', expected: ''Google'', reason: actual value is not JSON-like abc.feature:16 - path: $.title, actual: 'Google', expected: ''Google'', reason: actual value is not JSON-like
```

And If I use:

```
Then match driver.title == Google
```

I get below error:

```
javascript evaluation failed: driver.title, null
```

Additional details:

```
karate-junit4 = 9.4.0
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', showDriverLog: false }
```

As suggested in the comments, used  0.9.5.RC3 as well.
Received this error:

```
assertion failed: path: $, actual: '', expected: 'Google', reason: not equal
```

Can anyone point out If I am missing anything here?

Comment: works for me. please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: also please try 0.9.5.RC3

Comment: Hope it will help. https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/913

Answer (score 0):

Last Update: This issue was a bug with 0.9.4. Please see detail description from the below link: Issue link: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/913